# Как сделать дату и время на js у всех одинаковой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как установить у всех одинаковую таймзону, я получаю с базы данных дату типа 2000-01-01 00:00:00
И мне нужно установить обратный отсчет, когда устанавливаю у всех выдает разное время.
Как в js эту дату определить как московское, если осталось 2 часа то у всех было 2 а ?

Comment: А как именно вы устанавливаете у себя обратный отсчёт? Пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://codepen.io/vsjerkil/pen/QWELBMW?editors=1010

Comment: Как вариант, можно пойти другим путем и устанавливать не дату-время (до которого вести отчёт), а на сервере рассчитывать оставшееся время и просто вести отсчёт от него до нуля.

Comment: Например, с сервера получил что осталось 3 часа, как это я могу встроить в мой код ? Просто в js не очень разбираюсь